# What Are the Types of Deconvolution?

Tags: image-processing, deconvolution, reconstruction, inverse-problem

I am totally new to image processing and wanted to ask you if you could confirm what I understood. It is about deconvolution:

From what I read we find 2 main types of deconvolution:

**1. Analytical**

```
   i.Linear : inverse filter, Wiener deconvolution..  
   ii. non linear : maximum  entropy  method , CLEAN algorithm..
```

**2. numerical**

Is this right ? If I need deconvolution for deblurring, how do I proceed to choose the right algorithm? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, Anything missing in my question? If not, could you please mark it? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can classify using the following main properties:

1. Blind Deconvolution.
2. Non Blind Deconvolution.

Then I'd follow:

- Linear Model.

  - Time / Spatial Invariant Model.
  - Time / Spatial Variant Model.
- Non Linear Model.

  - Time / Spatial Invariant Model.
  - Time / Spatial Variant Model.

I think those are the main properties of a Deconvolution Problem.
The hardest would be Blind Deconvolution with Non Linear Model of Variant Operator.